# How to denote mutable parameters in closures with Swift > 2.2?

Tags: swift, closures, swift3

Perhaps this is an Xcode 8 beta issue, however, prior to 2.2 the `var` keyword is allowed to prepend parameters in function signatures:

```
func (var stringName: String) { ... }
```

This is has since been deprecated in lieu of there being little benefit over `inout`

```
func (stringName: inout String) { ... }
```

I've attempted the following in a `map` closure, and though I don't receive a deprecation warning as mildly expected I should, the error was rather a `segmentation fault: 11`

```
let demoString = ["hi", "there", "world"].map { (var word) -> String in 
    let firstChar = word.remove(at: word.startIndex)
}
```

The error kicks in as soon as I attempt to mutate the (assumedly mutable) `word` variable.

I've attempted other variation e.g. using `inout`

```
let demoString = ["hi", "there", "world"].map { (word: inout String) -> String in 
    let firstChar = word.remove(at: word.startIndex)
}
```

But the compiler complains that this erroneously changes the signature of the closure altogether and won't compile.

Obviously, the workaround is simply to copy the variable to a local one within the closure:

```
let demoString = ["hi", "there", "world"].map { (word) -> String in 
    let tempWord = word
    let firstChar = tempWord.remove(at: tempWord.startIndex)
}
```

However, I am interested in knowing if this is expected functionality & whether or not there is a way of mutating a parameter passed into a closure directly?

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Closures can mutate `inout` arguments just fine:

```
var str1 = "Pine"
var str2 = "Juniper"

let closure = { (s1: inout String, s2: inout String) -> Void in
    s1 = "Oak"
    s2 = "Chestnut"
}

closure(&str1, &str2)

print(str1, str2)
```

The problem you are facing is `Array.map` doesn't have a method signature that includes an `inout` parameter.

The only way around this that I can think of is to extend Array and add the `map` method yourself:

```
extension Array {
    func map<T>(_ closure: (inout T) -> Void) -> Array<T> {
        var arr = [T]()
        for i in 0..<self.count {
            var temp : T = self[i] as! T
            closure(&temp)
            arr.append(temp)
        }
        return arr
    }
}

var hi = "hi", there = "there", world = "world"
var demoStrings = [hi, there, world]
var result = demoStrings.map { (word: inout String) in 
    word.remove(at: word.startIndex)
}

print(result) // ["i", "here", "orld"]
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [SE-0003](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0003-remove-var-parameters.md) `var` parameters no longer exist in Swift 3.

Fundamentally, you shouldn't be mutating the parameters given from `map`, anyway. Instead: use non-mutating functions, or make a local mutable copy.

In this case, there's no reason to be using `remove(_:)` just to get the first character. This would require copying a String's memory (omitting the first character), solely to get the character that was removed. It's quite clunky.

In this case, you can just get the [`first`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1640976-first) property (from the [`Collection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection) protocol) on the [`characters`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1540072-characters) property of [`String`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string).

Try this:

```
let demoStrings = ["hi", "there", "world"]

let firstLetters = demoStrings.map {(word: String) -> String in
    return word.characters.first
}
```

or for short:

```
let firstLetters = demoStrings.map{ $0.characters.first }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm not actually looking for a way to rewrite the expression. It's just there for demo purposes. I'm trying to find out whether parameters passed into closures can be mutated. FYI `word.characters.first` if all you need is the first letter.

Comment: Oh of course, I have no clue why `.first` didn't come to mind lol

Comment: You can have closures with `inout` parameters, but you can't use such a closure for `map`, because of the declaration of map's closure (which doesn't use `inout`)